# Transfer files over WiFi from Windows to iPad

Tags: windows, wireless-networking, file-transfer, ipad

Any idea how to transfer (large) files from Windows to an iPad over an an-hoc WiFi network?

I am looking for a direct solution, without having to wait for my files to be uploaded to some internet service and then downloaded back into the iPad (so no using Dropbox or email).

Comment: Have you tried the app [Air Transfer](https://itunes.apple.com/app/air-transfer-easy-file-document/id521595136?mt=8&ign-mpt=uo%3D4)?

Answer (score 0):

You can use teamviewer to transfer files between windows, linux, iOS.  It can work over the internet, (and you need to authenticate via internet connection), but if available will default to transferring over a local wifi network.